# Logging In the Aeron

Tags: java, logging, elk, aeron

I'm looking for a solution to log all requests/errors in a log file to parse logs with ELK
Is there any best practice or sample? or what's the Aeron recommendation for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Aeron can be monitored and inspected using the following tools:

https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Monitoring-and-Debugging

Comment: I think the CnC file is an excellent solution to persist metrics but to have full logs such as stack trace, is it a good choice?

Comment: We used a ring buffer to remove the impact of logging on the performance of the application. All we did was use Agrona Agent and develop some method to take logs and put them into ring buffer and a separate thread read from the buffer and logs it into the console.